# Type-safe Parser-Combinators in Scala

Tags: scala, declarative, parser-combinators, postfix-notation

I was inspired to use reverse polish notation as an example of parser combinators for a course I will be teaching, however, my solution ends up using the type `List[Any]` to store floating point numbers and binary operators respectively. In the end, I recursively deconstruct the list and apply binary operators whenever I meet them. The entire implementation is here:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

trait Ops {
  type Op = (Float,Float) => Float

  def add(x: Float, y: Float) = x + y
  def sub(x: Float, y: Float) = x - y
  def mul(x: Float, y: Float) = x * y
  def div(x: Float, y: Float) = x / y
}

trait PolishParser extends Ops with JavaTokenParsers {

  // Converts a floating point number as a String to Float
  def num: Parser[Float] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (_.toFloat)
  // Parses an operator and converts it to the underlying function it logically maps to
  def operator: Parser[Op] = ("*" | "/" | "+" | "-") ^^ {
    case "+" => add
    case "-" => sub
    case "*" => mul
    case "/" => div
  }

}

trait PolishSemantics extends PolishParser {

  def polish:Parser[Float] = rep(num | operator) ^^ ( xs => reduce(xs).head )

  def pop2(xs:List[Float],f:Op) = (xs take 2 reduce f) :: (xs drop 2)

  def reduce(input:List[Any],stack:List[Float] = Nil):List[Float] = input match {
    case (f:Op) :: xs => reduce(xs,pop2(stack,f))
    case (x:Float) :: xs => reduce(xs,x :: stack)
    case Nil => stack
    case _ => sys.error("Unexpected input")
  }

}

class PolishInterpreter extends PolishParser with PolishSemantics {
  // Parse an expression and return the calculated result as a String
  def interpret(expression: String) = parseAll(polish, expression)
}

object Calculator extends PolishSemantics {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pi = new PolishInterpreter
    println("input: " + args(0))
    println("result: " + pi.interpret(args(0)))
  }

}
```

What I want to achieve is to not use the type-pattern in the reduce function. One solution is of course to make a custom type hierarchy in the following sense:

```
trait Elem
case class Floating(f:Float) extends Elem
case class Operator(o: (Float,Float) => Float) extends Elem
```

By this, I would be able to use pattern matching on case-classes through their unapply methods, but this would also require extensive refactoring of the code.
One other approach could be to apply the semantics directly while parsing, which would allow me to use only a "stack" of floats and then deal with operators immediately after parsing them. This would of course totally ruin the declarative fashion in which the parser-combinators work and would be a crime against everything that is good in the world.

I realize, of course, that this is nit-picking, but inside everyone is a software engineer trying to get out, and I am ready for that last suggestion to make the example perfect. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Do the `Elem` thing.  You basically want to build up a syntax tree for your little language, parsing from the input string into syntax.  Then you can translate the syntax into the semantics with your recursive function.

Comment: Hmm yes, I'm guessing that I should spend some more time with the general problem: What are advantages/disadvantages of the type-pattern compared to an unapply pattern? I know there is an article on related thoughts here: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf